# String Array on ESP32

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I need to implement a string array, like:

```
String[] txt = {"some text1", "some text2", "some text3", "some text4"};
```

The standard `char[]` doesn't suit me. How can I use string Array or List in Arduino IDE for ESP32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're free to use all STL facilities, including an array of strings. Standard caveats apply (dynamic RAM allocation from heap, STL uses lots of Flash for code, etc)

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

std::array<std::string> my_array = {"text1", "text2"};
```